# TextWatcher filter for an object with custom toString()

Tags: android, textwatcher

I'm trying to filter a custom ListView - from a ListActivity. The problem is, while the filter is actually working, the ListView is not displaying correctly.

If for example I have 3 items each starting with a, b, c, da, db respectively, typing in e will show that the ListView is empty. However, when I type in b, it will show a, and when I type in c, it will show a. When I type in d, it will show a, b. I'm not entirely certain what I did wrong or what I'm missing to have that issue. It appears that the position isn't being passed to the filter, but how would I go about doing this?

Below is the my ArrayAdapter:

```
private class SiteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Site> {
    private ArrayList<Site> sites;

    public SiteAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Site> sites) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, sites);
        this.sites = sites;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        }
        Site s = this.sites.get(position);
        if (s != null) {
            TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.toptext);
            TextView bt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.bottomtext);
            TextView rt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.statustext);
            if (tt != null) {
                tt.setText("sup2");
            }
            if (bt != null) {
                bt.setText("sup");
            }
            if (rt != null) {
                rt.setText("sup");
            }
        }
        v.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(position));
        return v;
    }

    private class OnItemClickListener implements OnClickListener{           
        private int mPosition;
        OnItemClickListener(int position){
                mPosition = position;
        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            //Log.v("MainActivity", sites.get(mPosition).getURL());
            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Wee.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent,1);
        }               
    }
}


private TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        site_adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
    }
};

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    filterText.removeTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
}
```

My Object Class has:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return new StringBuilder()
    .append(this.SEARCHABLE).toString();
}
```

I got it down to filtering correctly, but now the filter isn't returning the Listview to its original state when deleting or emptying the text box. I got the example from [Custom Filtering ArrayAdapter in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492214/custom-filtering-arrayadapter-in-listview):

```
private class SiteFilter extends Filter {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            String prefix = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

            if (prefix == null || prefix.length() == 0) {
                ArrayList<Site> list = new ArrayList<Site>(sites);
                results.values = list;
                results.count = list.size();
            } else {
                final ArrayList<Site> list = new ArrayList<Site>(sites);
                final ArrayList<Site> nlist = new ArrayList<Site>();
                int count = list.size();

                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    final Site pkmn = list.get(i);
                    final String value = pkmn.getFILTERABLETEXT().toLowerCase();

                    if (value.startsWith(prefix)) {
                        nlist.add(pkmn);
                    }
                }
                results.values = nlist;
                results.count = nlist.size();
            }
            return results;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            filtered_sites = (ArrayList<Site>) results.values;

            clear();
            int count = filtered_sites.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                Site pkmn = (Site) filtered_sites.get(i);
                add(pkmn);
            }
        }
    }
```

Chandra's advice:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            filtered_sites = (ArrayList<Site>) results.values;
            site_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            clear();
            int count = filtered_sites.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                Site pkmn = (Site) filtered_sites.get(i);
                add(pkmn);
                Log.d("OMGOMGOMG",pkmn.getURL());
            }
            site_adapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its not notifying the change in data. Add `notifyDataSetChanged` in method `onTextChanged`

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    site_adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
    site_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not solve the issue. I thought publishResults did the notifyDataSetChanged()?

Comment: I don't think so. Since you are using custom filter, you will have to call this in `publishResults`. Also, you may have to call `notifyDataSetInvalidated` in `publishResults`. This thread [Custom filtering in Android using ArrayAdapter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718202/custom-filtering-in-android-using-arrayadapter) might help

Comment: I just added notifyDataSetInvalidated in publishResults and it still did not work. However, it did do something: Now, when I type in l, delete, and type in l again, it keeps the same data because it's searching the active stuff on the screen.

Comment: Oh. Did you also add `notifyDataSetChanged();`, before `clear()` in publishResults?

Comment: I updated with the possible changes I made as per your advice.

Comment: Also, look at the  thread you have included. As it says, change `this.sites = sites;`, to `this.sites = new ArrayList<Site>(sites);'

Comment: When I added new ArrayList<Site>(sites); it gave me this error: 06-27 20:01:16.122: E/AndroidRuntime(28015): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13134/discussion-between-rijvi-rajib-and-chandra)