# How to make MultiAutoCompleteTextView to search for substrings

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

How can I make my MultiAutoCompleteTextView to search within the strings of each list location(means search the substring too). Is there any attribute I need to set or is it even possible?
For example if one of the list object is "abc123", then is it possible to include this in suggestions of autocomplete by typing 123?

Comment: Have you tried this example :-http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/07/example-of-multiautocompletetextview.html

Comment: yeah, this example also has the same problem as mine..

Comment: For this you need to implement a custom array adapter a with custom filtering go here for further help :-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492214/custom-filtering-arrayadapter-in-listview

Answer (score 1):

For go on this link and try this,

http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/07/example-of-multiautocompletetextview.html

> MultiAutoCompleteTextView is an editable text view, extending
>   AutoCompleteTextView, that can show completion suggestions for the
>   substring of the text where the user is typing instead of necessarily
>   for the entire thing.
>
> You must must provide a MultiAutoCompleteTextView.Tokenizer to
>   distinguish the various substrings.

main.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    />
<MultiAutoCompleteTextView android:id="@+id/multiautocompletetextview"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:completionThreshold="1"
 />
```

Java main code:

```java
package com.exercise.AndroidMultiAutoCompleteTextView;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.MultiAutoCompleteTextView;

public class AndroidMultiAutoCompleteTextView extends Activity {

 MultiAutoCompleteTextView myMultiAutoCompleteTextView;
 String item[]={
   "January", "February", "March", "April",
   "May", "June", "July", "August",
   "September", "October", "November", "December"
 };

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        MultiAutoCompleteTextView myMultiAutoCompleteTextView 
         = (MultiAutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(
           R.id.multiautocompletetextview);

        myMultiAutoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(
          new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, item));
        myMultiAutoCompleteTextView.setTokenizer(
          new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer());

    }
}
```

Comment: this example has same problem.. tried to findout 'september' by typing 'tem' in edittextbox but no suggestions :( i want to make search active for substrings too.